# Termination app due to uncaught exception, cannot init a class object

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring

I use SOAP to get Time from website, when executes the following souce code, it raises problem.
I guess the line 4 at below source code has problem, but I don't know how to fix, please help.
Thanks.

Source Code:

```
-(void) parse:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *) elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
 if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"getOffesetUTCTimeResult"])
{
    greeting.text = [[[NSString init] strinWithFormat:@"The local time is:", nameInput.text] stringByAppending:soapResults];
    [soapResults release];
    soapResults = nil;
}
}
```

Raised error:

`*** Termination app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '** +[NSString <0x267fd8> init]: cnnot init a class object.' 
*** First throw call stack:
...
terminate called throwing an exception`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call the initializer without `alloc`ing memory for objects. For `NSString`, you can do something like:

```
greeting.text = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The local time is:", nameInput.text] stringByAppending:soapResults];
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to init `NSString`.

Just use

```
greeting.text = [[NSString strinWithFormat:@"The local time is:", nameInput.text] stringByAppending:soapResults];
```